# What is wrong with this java code (quick)

Tags: java

```
public class Square {

  private int sideLength;

  private int area;

  public Square(int initialLength) {

    sideLength = initialLength;

    area = sideLength * sideLength;

  }

  public int getArea() { return area; }

  public void grow() { sideLength = 2 * sideLength; }

}
```

I don't know whats wrong and how to fix it. I think its because I set sideLength to initialLength and its basically the same thing?

Comment: `private int area` is redundant. You can just `return sideLength * sideLength` from `getArea()`.

Comment: Nothing is wrong! It only *may* not produce what you expect, but you did not yet specify what you expect, what it produces and why you might think that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

In your `grow` method, since you're updating the value of `sideLength`, you should also update the value of `area`:

```
public void grow() {
    sideLength = 2 * sideLength;
    area = sideLength * sideLength;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvoted (I gave it an upvote!). The goal is to have the "getArea()" method always return the side length squared. When you update the side length, the returned area needs to be updated as well. I admit, that the code isn't the prettiest, but it is functionally correct.